# How to find out a texture's format in GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl, textures, shader

I am working on a shader for different image bit depths and a lookup table.
So what I have works nicely but for the lookup I need to know the internal format of the texture. Actually that is only indirectly the truth, but it would serve me completely. So this is what I have:

```
        #version 150
        precision highp float;

        uniform samplerBuffer LutData; 
        uniform sampler2D Texture;     
        void main() 
        { 
            color = texture(Texture, fragTexCoord);
            // R16 grayscale texture - handle 16bit wise mono
            float primaryLvl = color.r;
            int index = int(primaryLvl * 65535);
            float gray = texelFetch(LutData, index).r;
            finalColor = vec4(gray, gray, gray, 1);
        }
```

Shortened version (so may not work)

What I need is this (pseudocode + only main):

```
        void main() 
        { 
            // need follows here:
            int lutspread = gettextureparam(Texture, MaxRange);

            color = texture(Texture, fragTexCoord);
            // R16 grayscale texture - handle 16bit wise mono
            float primaryLvl = color.r;
            int index = int(primaryLvl * lutspread);
            float gray = texelFetch(LutData, index).r;
            finalColor = vec4(gray, gray, gray, 1);
        }
```

Does such a thing exist?

So that `lutspread` is either 255 or 65535. Because what "normal" samplers do is: They inperpret texture integers as normalized integers which results in 32-bit float values between 0.0-1.0. And it does not make a difference whether the texture format is RED8 or RED16 it only is more or less granular! However if a LUT is part of the game this feature is contra productive because a LUT wants raw data.

BTW: I already had my less successful tries using `GL_REDui` and `GL_RED_INTEGER` as texture generating parameters. I fear it makes me more problems than my current approach using `GL_RED8`/`GL_RED16` + `GL_LUMINANCE`

You can tell me to go that path but I will be very scared to loose things I have so far. Ultimately I'll introduce a uniform and use that as my factor.

Answer (score 1):

Any particular reason why adding a single int uniform is so bad?

Apart from the uniform, the only solution that could work (if LutData is of the proper size) to use textureSize on LutData, but I'd consider that an ugly hack.

The best solution would be the one you tried to use - if you'd tell us why it became problematic, maybe we could help? Have you used GL_RED with GL_R32UI?

Comment: The Problem was that the whole image was the same gray shade. Could not really find out what was happening. Thereby implying that the code vec4 color = texture(usampler2D) would yield for example vec4(1234.0f,,,) == eg not range 0.0-1.0